# Iterating over a 2d sliding window over a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, performance, image-processing

I have a function `my_fun` which works on a `kxk` window of an image and returns a scalar.

I want to iterate over the image pixels and extract, for each pixel, a window of size `kxk` around it.
The `k` parameter is an odd number.

I am looking for an iterator, similar to Matlab `nlfilter`.

What would be fast and also with minimal memory overhead?

It should be like:

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
win_radius = (1, 1) # k = 3

for i in range(my_array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(my_array.shape[1]):
        win_rows = max(0, i - win_radius[0]), min(my_array.shape[0], i + win_radius[0] + 1)
        win_cols = max(0, j - win_radius[1]), min(my_array.shape[1], j + win_radius[1] + 1)
        my_win = my_array[win_rows[0]:win_rows[1], win_cols[0]:win_cols[1]]
        print(my_win)
```

the output is:

```py
[[0 1]
 [5 6]]
[[0 1 2]
 [5 6 7]]
[[1 2 3]
 [6 7 8]]
[[2 3 4]
 [7 8 9]]
[[3 4]
 [8 9]]
[[ 0  1]
 [ 5  6]
 [10 11]]
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 5  6  7]
 [10 11 12]]
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [11 12 13]]
[[ 2  3  4]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [12 13 14]]
[[ 3  4]
 [ 8  9]
 [13 14]]
...
[[17 18 19]
 [22 23 24]]
[[18 19]
 [23 24]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view()`:

```
arr = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)), (2, 3))
```

for a sliding window of `2 x 3`, for example.